# Visual Studio 2012 error on adding Resources file to the SharePoint 2013 feature: the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio

There is an error in Visual Studio 2012 when add resources file to the SharePoint feature: "the system cannot find the file specified".

How to resolve it?

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too.. Probalby you can workaround by just adding some special tags into the Manifest of the Feature.
I will check the upper with SP2010 and try to provide a solution (not fully altruistic, since i need it myself ;-))

Comment: I tried to add it by hand, but it seems not be deployed into the FeatureFiles...
I just edited the *.templates to this:
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<ElementManifests>
    <ElementFile Location="Resources\Resources.resx" />
    <ElementFile Location="Resources\Resources.de-DE.resx" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay some Googling gave the answer. It's a known bug with VS2012 Office Tools and they will fix it:
 http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764660/error-on-adding-resources-file-to-the-sharepoint-2013-feature-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-0x80070002
The workaround proposed by AlexBB worked well for me.